# SlidingDrawer and imageview in android

Tags: android-layout

I have a `imageView` in a tab. So basically tab just opens an `imageView`. I want to have a `SlidingDrawer`, but seems like `imageView` and `SlidingDrawer` doesn't show up together. Does anybody know how to make them work together?

My xml for the tab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/busroute" />

     <SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Route List" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />

    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. Basically LinearLayout is the problem. I switched to RelativeLayout and tweak on that layout.